# Is log4net.GlobalContext.Properties different per request?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, asp.net-web-api, log4net

In log4net, I want to append a request id to every log statement for a particular http request.  Request id's are distinct across multiple requests.  In my global.asax.cs I assign a requestId.

```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["requestId"] =
    System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
      log.Info("Starting request.");  
    }
```

In my Log4Net.config I added the requestId to my pattern layout:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
 <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%property{requestId} %d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
</layout>
```

Is the approach of using GlobalContext to set a variable threadsafe?  Am I at risk of a concurrent http request
unsafely changing the requestId for the logging of another request?

If this is unsafe, what is a safe way to implement?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No it is not correct; the global context is shared across all threads and domains. Two threads setting the same property on the `GlobalContext` would overwrite one another's property. `log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["requestId"]` will always contain the request id of the latest request started.

Being [threadsafe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) doesn't mean thread independent: it means that the object can be manipulated by multiple threads at the same time.

Use the `ThreadContext` which lives per thread and will let you have a property per thread (hence per request, assuming your thread doesn't delegate work to another thread at some point):
`log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["requestId"]`

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have chosen LogicalThreadContext, which I believe is useful when using await/async, ie, different threads may handle the request at various points in the async lifecycle.

Comment: @user1483903 That's great but did you have a chance to test that? I was under the impression that it was useful in custom thread pooling and management

Comment: @user1483903 You probably already know this by now, but LogicalThreadContext should do what you want.  It is implemented using CallContext.LogicalSetData/LogicalGetData.  The Logical[Get|Set]Data calls are useful because data that is stored using those functions will get passed to child threads.  So, if you are processing a request and you store the request id (or some identifier) and then use subthreads (or tasks) to actually perform the request, the subthreads (or tasks) will have access to the same request id that you stored up front.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. 
I have exactly this scenario, a multi-threading application that must send different information to the log depends on the thread context.

Using ThreadContext instead of GlobalContext works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This type is safe for multithreaded operations. 
([log4net.GlobalContext Documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.GlobalContext.html))

edit: doc links might get updated, this worked for v 1.2.15.
[GlobalContextProperties](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/?topic=html/T_log4net_Util_GlobalContextProperties.htm)

Quote:

*This class implements a properties collection that is thread safe and supports both storing properties and capturing a read only copy of the current propertied. This class is optimized to the scenario where the properties are read frequently and are modified infrequently.*

Comment: Have you downgraded this because link is stale? I'd really like to know.